# How to store result of SQL set operation in new table directly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL. I am working with SQL Server 2012. I would like to store the result of a set operation (e.g. `INTERSECT`) in a new table. I have done this in an indirect way: stored the set operation results in a view and then copied the contents of the view into my new table using `SELECT * INTO myNewTable FROM myView`. How do I do this without using a view as an intermediate step?

Thanks!

-Rohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options that don't require an intermediate view to be created. For example, a subquery:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.myNewTable FROM 
(
  SELECT a,b,c FROM dbo.t1 
  INTERSECT 
  SELECT a,b,c FROM dbo.t2
) AS x;
```

Or a [common table expression (CTE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT a,b,c FROM dbo.t1 
  INTERSECT 
  SELECT a,b,c FROM dbo.t2
)
SELECT * INTO dbo.myNewTable FROM x;
```